# What is the advantage of using a service in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a question, why symfony use a service instead of "use" directly into a controller.

I have a class named DisplayManager and I declare this class as a service.

Why not use DisplayManager directly into a controller using "*use DisplayManager*"

Thanks

Comment: For one, because that tightly couples your controller to DisplayManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The advantage of thinking about "services" is that you begin to think about separating each piece of functionality in your application into a series of services. Since each service does just one job, you can easily access each service and use its functionality wherever you need it. Each service can also be more easily tested and configured since it's separated from the other functionality in your application. This idea is called [service-oriented architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) and is not unique to Symfony or even PHP. Structuring your application around a set of independent service classes is a well-known and trusted object-oriented best-practice. These skills are key to being a good developer in almost any language.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

**Questions that suggest define your class as service:**

- My class is used in several places in my application?
- My class has many dependencies?

There is a good example for these topics here:

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#what-is-a-service-container

**Performance Advantage:**

The service has a default condition that allows to the related class instantiate it only once.

Imagine a class with 5 dependencies (and these as well with their dependencies) and has been used in 20 parts of our system, what if we do not define this class as a service?

However define your class as a service is not required, this will always depend on the architecture of your system and the mission to be fulfilled its class, in addition to the dependencies you have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can write the class DisplayManager separately from my controller and if I want to use the service of this class why not use diretement use my controller instead of using a service? I love avoire good basic programming object.

Comment: You want a service because the Container takes care of instantiation for you. So if you later realize your service needs to take a constructor argument, you only need to modify the services.xml instead of finding all the places where you used it directly in controllers and updating them.

Comment: @princebabay I don't know really that you need, but if you have already defined the service why you are asking by use it with `use` statement? why not simply `$this->get('your_service_name')` within controller?

Comment: I would just like to know what is the advantage between using $ this-> get ( 'your_service_name') instead of "use" directly into a controller for example

Comment: @princebabay, if you use a "use", this is just an include of the class. You will have to instantiate it and the constructor will very probably expect some parameters and/or classes to inject. Moreover, you will have several instances of a class which is "re-usable" most of the time. The best example of a service is a mailer: the mailer has tons of parameters (protocol, port, login, ...). Now imagine that you have to instantiate your mailer in ten different controllers or other services ...

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are made only to take requests (http) and produce a response (http). No more. Never.

Services are totally independent classes that you can use everywhere. Moreover, with services, you can take advantage of `DependencyInjection`.

Services are more testable.

Services (like controllers and whatever) must have only a responsibility.

And so on ...